# HTML5 IMAGE MAPPING

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, mapping

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Answer 6</title></head>
    <body>
        <img src="C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\map_image.jpg" usemap="#new">
        <map name="new">
        </map>
        <area shape="rect"coords="68,51,275,182" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_America">
        <area shape="rect"coords="501,57,736,221" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia">
        <area shape="rect"coords="206,239,321,405" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_America">
        <area shape="rect"coords="345,173,474,361" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa">
        <area shape="rect"coords="142,449,726,495" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica">
        <area shape="rect"coords="661,311,768,375" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia">
        <area shape="rect"coords="379,63,492,142" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe">
        </map>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am just not getting it that where lies the error!!!!!!!!!!!
I have done mapping correctly but still when I click on the image it does not maps to the link!!
Please can anyone explain??

Comment: Consider removing the ` </map>` before the first `<area`?

Comment: You cannot use local paths such as "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\" as you are here.

Comment: https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/51-517422_world-map-continent-world-ocean-world-map-6.png       here is the link for this image

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you so much, today I got to know memes do have importance in a programmer's life. What a silly mistake I did

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the extra closing tag for `</map>` and it will work

**Update** working example:

```html
<body>
    <img style="border: 5px solid black" src="https://i.ibb.co/kJW37VH/Screen-Shot-2021-06-18-at-7-00-41-PM.png" usemap="#new">
    <map name="new">
        <area shape="rect"coords="0,0,320,320" href="https://google.com">
        <area shape="rect"coords="320,0,640,320" href="https://fb.com">
    </map>
</body>
```

you have to remove the extra closing tag for `</map>` and it will work

Comment: Consider adding a snippet or example to the answer?